# mini batch matrix form of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I am studying neural network. I read a lot about mini-batch gradient descent. So now, I was implementing it in TensorFlow.

But I have some questions regarding the matrix formulation of the problem/vectorization.

**Notation**

First some notation 
$w_{ij}^l$ is the weight on the connection connecting node $j$ in layer $l$ to node $i$ in layer $l+1$.

If we have $4$ nodes and $3$ features we could have:

$W^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
    w_{11}^{(1)}       & w_{12}^{(1)}    & w_{13}^{(1)}  \\
    w_{21}^{(1)}       & w_{22}^{(1)}    & w_{23}^{(1)}  \\
    w_{31}^{(1)}       & w_{32}^{(1)}    & w_{33}^{(1)}  \\
    w_{41}^{(1)}       & w_{42}^{(1)}    & w_{43}^{(1)}
\end{bmatrix}$

At the same time, suppose we have a batch size of $5$, then the input matrix might be

$X = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12}    & x_{13}  \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22}    & x_{23}  \\
    x_{31}       & x_{32}    & x_{33}  \\
    x_{41}       & x_{42}    & x_{43}   \\
    x_{51}       & x_{52}    & x_{53}
\end{bmatrix}$

where $x_{ij}$ is the input in sample $i$ of feature $j$.

**What I don't understand**

Everywhere I go I see $f(W^TX +\mathbb{b})$ as the formula. However this clearly doesn't make sense here, as we would have incompatible shapes!! $W$ has shapes $(\text{number nodes}, \text{number features})$, while $X$ has shape  $($ batch size, number features $)$.

Ideally we would like, for each sample, to have something like this (I only write the first two columns). But how do we get there? Is this the correct way?

$A^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
    w_{11}^{(1)}x_{11}       + w_{12}^{(1)}x_{12}   + w_{13}^{(1)}x_{13} & w_{11}^{(1)}x_{21}       + w_{12}^{(1)}x_{22}   + w_{13}^{(1)}x_{23}\\
    w_{21}^{(1)} x_{11}      + w_{22}^{(1)}x_{12}    + w_{23}^{(1)}x_{13}  & w_{11}^{(1)}x_{21}       + w_{12}^{(1)}x_{22}   + w_{13}^{(1)}x_{23}\\
    w_{31}^{(1)}x_{11}       + w_{32}^{(1)}x_{12}    + w_{33}^{(1)}x_{13}  & w_{31}^{(1)}x_{31}       + w_{32}^{(1)}x_{32}    + w_{33}^{(1)}x_{33}\\
    w_{41}^{(1)}x_{11}       + w_{42}^{(1)}x_{12}    + w_{43}^{(1)}x_{13} &  w_{41}^{(1)}x_{41}       + w_{42}^{(1)}x_{42}    + w_{43}^{(1)}x_{43}
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem.  Here's a neural net with three layers:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
y = \beta_0 + \mathbf{V}_1\beta \\
\mathbf{V}_1 = a(\gamma_1 + \mathbf{V}_2\Gamma_1)\\
\mathbf{V}_2 = a(\gamma_2 + \mathbf{V}_3\Gamma_2)\\
\mathbf{V}_3 = a(\gamma_3 + \mathbf{X}\Gamma_3)
\end{array}
$$

Where $\mathbf{X}$ is your data.

Say that $\mathbf{X}$ is $N \times p$.  That means that $\Gamma_3$ is $p \times p_3$, $\mathbf{V}_3$ is therefore $N \times p_3$ and $\Gamma_2$ is $p_3 \times p_2$, $\mathbf{V}_2$ is therefore $N \times p_2$ and $\Gamma_1$ is $p_2 \times p_1$, and $\beta$ is $p_1 \times 1$ (assuming a univariate response).

For a minibatch, just swap out $N$ with $B<N$.  It doesn't change the dimensions of the weights, just that of the derived variables/hidden layers $\mathbf{V}$

Your problem is that you were thinking of $X$ as row-oriented vs column oriented, I think.  That's why your matrices weren't conformable.  But minibatch has nothing to do with that -- minibatch chops off observations, not features.  Dropout, on the other hand, chops off features.  In so doing it propagates the deleted columns upward/downward on the forward backward passes.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, here $\gamma_i$ are the biases, right?

Comment: Right.  Although that terminology is STUPID.  They should be called "intercepts".

Comment: right, like in linear regression!

Comment: Also $p_3$ is the number of nodes in hidden layer 1 ?

Comment: Inevitably!  I am of the opinion that the tensor-based and index based way that neural nets are taught makes them seem needlessly complex, especially to people with a wit of math background.

Comment: Hidden layer 1 (or, the first from the bottom) *is* $\mathbf{V}_3$ in my terminology.  It is nothing but a set of derived variables.  That is what neural nets are.  Iterative sets of derived variables, eventually related to the outcome by OLS or logistic regression.

Comment: Makes sense, it is basically a linear regression where instead of using the input $x$ you use a transformation of it, and you do this transformation through various layers.

But what I don't understand is how the computer multiplies these matrices. $X$ is $N\times p$ and that's okay. The weight matrix of the first hidden layer, $\Gamma_3$ is $p \times p_3$ and that is okay. But why do we know that $V_2$ is $N \times p_3$?

Comment: By knowing $X$ is $N \times p$ and $\Gamma_3$ is $p\times p_3$, we know that $V_3$ is $N \times p_3$

Comment: Yeah, basically.

Comment: My doubt is that when I did linear algebra, I was told that by multiplying a vector/matrix with another matrix ON THE LEFT, I could do a transformation. Intuitively, I would transformate the input $X$ to the hidden nodes, not the opposite!

Comment: IDK but I'm fairly confident that you could use commutative rules for matrices to make this work in row-wise representations of data.

Comment: Also, shouldn't $V_2$ be $N \times p_2$?

Comment: And shouldn't $V_1$ be $N \times p_1$?

Comment: Yeah.  Editing..

Comment: Hey if I've answered your question, give me that check mark!

Comment: I think it makes sense, but then it means most implementations online are wrong.. which is quite weird

Comment: One last thing. Does this mean that you can "solve" a whole batch in one go using matrix notation?

Comment: You could if the activation function wasn't nonlinear.  That nonlinearity means that there isn't a closed form solution.  And what do you mean that online implementations are wrong?  They are probably internally consistent, but use a vocabulary that works better for computer scientists.

Comment: well they use tensorflow and they seem to end up with different shapes.. Maybe I'm just still confused

Comment: Any tensor can be represented in two dimensions. If you are writing code in assembly or for a GPU, the tensor representation might be optimal. But if you're relying on either blas or sparse matrix libraries, I think the 2d representation is better. But ultimately the two are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: If you're an R user, you might be interested in my package here:  https://github.com/cranedroesch/panelNNET.  It is in no way ready for release, but it implements the ideas that I'm talking about.